# jsf2 pass request parameter commandButton

Tags: jsf-2

I am using JSF2. I have a `commandButton` on whose action I am performing a navigation. The method I am calling on action returns a string where I am doing a redirect like this :

```
return "/orders/createOrder.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
```

My requirement is that I need to pass an additional parameter. But when I am returning like this, it does not redirect:

```
return "/orders/createOrder.xhtml?faces-redirect=true?another_Param=valueOfParam";
```

I am using this param for some other processing.

How can i pass this additional parameter using returning a string which is used in action of commandButton?

Comment: maybe /orders/createOrder.xhtml?faces-redirect=true&another_Param=valueOfParam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it using the following as commented by Leo :

return "/orders/createOrder.xhtml?faces-redirect=true&another_Param=valueOfParam";